# What's the thing in this function?

Tags: c++, function

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int apear (int dig, int num);

int main() {

int dig;
int num;

cin >> num;
cin >> dig;

apear (dig, num);

}


int apear (int dig, int num){

    int cont;
    if (num==0) return 0;

    if (num%10==dig)return 1 + apear(dig, num/10);
    else return apear (dig, num/10);
}
```

The idea of this function is to count how many times a digit appears in a number.
Example:
(3, 343353) cont=4
Dont know why it return 0 and doesn't return "cont"

Comment: According to your code,you should provide the number first then the digit to count, "example(3,343353" should be given **(353353,3)**. So with the input you provided the result is correct.

Comment: Your code is working. Maybe you forgot to print the result out cout << appear(dig, num);

Comment: The program looks OK to me. The error is most likely the order in which you provide input to the program. See it working at http://ideone.com/Ocm5D8.

Comment: do it with (3,343353) instead of (3, 343353)  and print it.

Comment: Also it will be good if u first provide the number and the enter the digit to be found. will look decent and more understandable. so modify the function accordingly if u want.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int apear (int num, int dig);

int main() {

int dig;
int num;
int occurence;

cin >> num;
cin >> dig;

occurence=apear (num, dig);
cout<<occurence;

return 0;
}


int apear (int num, int dig){

    int cont;
    if (num==0) return 0;

    if (num%10==dig)return 1 + apear(num/10, dig);
    else return apear (num/10, dig);
}
```

**PS: It's a bad practice when you are returning some value from function and no one is there in main function to catch the value.**

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the display of the returned value. It is the returned value(which is correct given the input) itself and with the input it is provided i.e **3** for the number and **353353** it will return 0 which is a correct result. I think the problem is most likely the order the inputs are given.

Comment: @bkVnet : thanks for pointing it...actually while compiling I provided the number first and then the digits....now have a look I modified the program.